# How to make isotope columnWidth work when first item is 2x the width of other items?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html says:

**First item breaks Masonry layout**

*With Masonry layout mode If you run into an issue where you re-size the first item, and all the rest of the items no longer fit together in the grid, you most likely need to set columnWidth option. Without columnWidth set, the Masonry layout mode will use the width of the first item for the size of its columns.*

```
$('#container').isotope(
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 220
  }
});
```

And this is what I'm currently doing. However I would like to have some CSS media queries that change the columnWidth. So if my first Isotope-item would have the normal 1x width, I could just specify the width of the items in the CSS and Isotope would take the columnWidth from there and work. But because my first item has 2x width, I have to specify the column width like in the code above, and of course then I can no longer change it with CSS.

**So is it possible to for example:**

- Make isotope take the columnWidth from the second item that has 1x width?
- Make some kind of hack so I would in fact have a 1x wide item as the first one but would set hide it with display:none or something?
- Set the Isotope columnWidth to take the width of the first item (which is 2x wide) minus 10px and divide by 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use CSS and media queries to set the size of your elements, then access that value in Javascript and use it to set the column width:

```
var colWidth = $('.column-width-isotope-element').width();

$('#container').isotope(
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: colWidth
  }
});
```

That way, the media query will be processed before isotope is initialized, and then it read the value of the column width (replace `.column-width-isotope-element` with whatever your selector is for a single-column width isotope element) and initialize isotope with that property.

Comment: This seems like the perfect solution, I'll try it right away. Thank you!

Comment: I recommend initializing on $(window).load rather than $(document).ready to make sure the stylesheet and images/other resources that may affect the element size has been loaded before the jQuery tries to access the width value.  Usually I use isotope with images so I always initialize it in window.load as a callback of the jQuery imagesLoaded plugin (there is more info / code example for this in the isotope docs somewhere).

Comment: I tried this and it seems that this has the same problem. I now have var colWidth = $('.column-width-isotope-element').width(); and I'm printing out the colWidth. It checks the first item with that class (which also has a .2x -class and is 2x wide) and takes the value from that one.

Comment: And if I try to take a value from CSS class that does not appear in the page, it wont return anything. Is it possible to take a value from straight from CSS, not from the item appearing page that has that class?

Comment: You could emulate media queries in JS by getting the window width and then setting the column width based on that with a few conditional statements that mirror your CSS media queries.  As far as I know you cannot directly parse a stylesheet from JS.  Or you can add a "dummy element" in the DOM whose width is set to the same as the column width (media queries included) and then use `.remove()` to remove it immediately after you measure its size and set the variable.

Comment: Note that these are all pretty sloppy "quick and dirty" basic methods for doing it.  for a more elegant (but more advanced) solution google around for `window.matchMedia` and JS media query techniques.

Comment: Thank you Ennui, I appreciate it very much.

I went with the "dummy element" -technique and added http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html this which sets the columnWidth variable again when resizing the window. It's now working perfectly and I'll see if I'll  try to find a prettier solution when the project is closer to the finish.

Answer (score 0):

I am using isotope jquery plugin v2.2.2 and faced that issue. I have added a css and it works for me.

```
.itl-portfolio-masonry:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```